# Hide cursor on textfield on pageload in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am working on a **ExtJS** project. I have a `textfiled` - Last Name. When I open the page it shows a blinking cursor on the `textfield`.

Expected is - Cursor should only appear when I click in the text box, not automatically on page load.

> Here is the code

```
 {
     xtype: 'textfield',
     name: 'lastName',
     //hasFocus : false,
     //readOnly : true, 
     //editable : false,

     id: 'patientSearchLastName',
     msgTarget: 'side',
     enableKeyEvents: true,
     fieldLabel: 'LAST NAME <span style="color:g">*</span>',
     labelAlign: 'top',
     fieldStyle: "font: bold 12px sans-serif;background:#fff;color:#444;",
     padding: 8,

     validator: function(value) {
         var isRequired = me.oneFieldRequired();
         if (typeof isRequired === "string")
             return isRequired;
         return me.validateName(value);
     },
     listeners: {

         specialkey: keyEnterListner,
         keyup: function(thisEl, e, eOpts) {
             me.validateFields(['firstName', 'identifierValue']);
         },
         blur: function(thisEl, e, eOpts) {
             me.validateFields(['firstName', 'identifierValue']);
         }
     }
 }
```

I have tried

```
hasFocus : false,
readOnly : true,
editable : false,
```

None of these worked, What should I do ?

Comment: Does it have a configurable autofocus option? If yes, set it to false. This would prevent the field to get focus on page load.

Comment: did not work ..

Comment: Provide this functions `oneFieldRequired`, 'validateName' and `validateFields` what you have written code in that function

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `hasFocus`, `editable` or `readOnly` on `afterrender` event?

```
afterrender: function (obj) {
    // try here
}
```